# IIS Express on a shared development machine (rdp)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-express

I have a problem which I thought could be common, searched the web for it but found nothing.

We're using a shared development machine, and every developer connects through RDP and has his own profile, desktop, etc.

The problem I am encountering is with IIS express. Since it is configured at user level (applicationhost.config inside documents/iisexpress/config) and the port configured must match the one declared in the .csproj file, two developers can't possibily run on the same port, as it gives the error "the port is already in use".

So to make it work we have to manually change the port both on the csproj and in the applicationhost.config for every developer, but it's only a temporary fix as when we commit our changes to SVN, the csproj file gets merged, so we have to do this process every time someone commits/updates.

My question is: is there a clean way to use IIS express with Visual Studio 2010 on a shared development machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be using the Visual Studio Development Server with auto-assigned ports be an option or do need to use IIS Express for a specific reason?

Comment: We would try to make IIS express work, as it reads the IIS configuration values declared in web.config, while Cassini doesn't. I know that Cassini with auto ports works, we just want to find a correct way to use IIS express.

Comment: FYI, IIS Express will be the default in the next Visual Studio release. I'm not sure that Cassini will even be available.

Comment: This question I made almost 3 years ago. Last week we finally got local individual desktops to develop on :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Partially tested answer. Not sure how it'll work on a multi-user workstation. It might give you, or someone else here, a jumpstart to a proper solution that works best in your existing environment.

It appears that Visual Studio stores all the web configuration in the csproj/vbproj and IISExpress stores its configuration in %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\ApplicationHost.Config.

Normally, we store the csproj files in source control, but ignore the csproj.user file so that each person may have some unique settings, such as the web configuration.

- Each user who signs into the box must have their own profile.
- Each profile must have their own copy of the source code.

  - Each user's copy of the source will contain their own csproj.user file.
- Ignore .**proj.user* files in your source control.

Copy the web settings into the csproj.user by unchecking the option *Apply server settings to all users* and then commit to source control.
[image: unchecking the option Apply server settings to all users]

Each user who pulls a copy of the source will have to configure their web settings, use a unique port that the others users are not using, and uncheck the box above so that their configuration is not passed on to the other users.

Doing this, Each profile will have their own IIS Express ApplicationHost.Config configured with a port that is different from the other profiles. Each user's copy of the source will have a csproj.user that is configured with the same port in their profile's IIS Express configuration.

For reference:

I've tried changing IIS Express's ApplicationHost.Config to use a different port than what Visual Studio expects and Visual Studio is unable to connect the debugger to IIS Express.

How IIS Express's configuration works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx

Comment: So simple, yet so amazing. Thanks. That works, and is the cleanest workaround to the "rdp" approach we have.

Comment: Has anyone tried this solution with Visual Studio 2013? It appears the checkbox to "Apply server settings to all users" has been removed, so I can't do this. I have this exact same issue.

Comment: I haven't checked myself, but it looks like it's back in VS2013 Update1. Here's the Connect ticket: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800003/the-apply-server-settings-to-all-users-store-in-project-file-option-is-missing-in-vs2013

Answer (score 0):

The best option you can use is to take advantage of the [Import functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) built into MSBuild.

Essentially, you would create a seperate build target for each user. You can then import this target from this referenced file directly. I would then recommend creating this file on the server (for each user), but leaving it outside of source control.

This should allow each user to have a custom IIS port without conflicting with others.

Comment: Would that mean to make a different target per user one time, or for each project? Because if it's oneshot it could be interesting, but if it needs to be repeated for each project, it could become a mess.

Comment: I haven't tested it directly yet, but it should be on a one time basis. As you would be importing a subset of the configuration file only related to the IIS settings. (though the imports line would have to be added per project one time, but could reference the same file)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create subdomains for each user and implement the required changes and do the testing. In this way each user can his own subdomain and port and hence work independently on the shared IIS Express.

Comment: a messy solution, bad for multiple projects.

Answer (score -1):

You probably won't like my answer but here's my thoughts:

As you noticed, the configurations are tied to the user profile and not the server; this is because IIS Express is not intended to be used as a shared development server. You should be using full IIS.

I do not see any benefit or reason to use the same physical box for development. Admittedly, I don't know all the details of your scenario with licensing or workstation resources, but it doesn't seem like you gain much from having everyone RDP into the box to use Visual Studio - each person still needs a license, performance will be slower, and you shouldn't be working on the same project instance.

You should seriously consider your entire setup for development:

Each developer should use Visual Studio on their workstation, and debug/test there using IIS Express (configured with the same ports and settings across all machines - very easy).

From there, your developers should check their code into source control, and examine conflicts that may or may not arise. I'm not sure about SVN but the MSBuild automation available in TFS can be use to setup a continuous build policy that deploys to a common IIS installation so that your merged code is tested and usable from the full IIS installation mentioned above.

*Anything else would be a workaround/hack that will bite you in the butt later.*

Comment: The local copy/svn part of your explanation is already like that. Every user has his own profile, his own desktop/settings etc, it's just that we have those 2 development servers (with same configuration, plugins installed, etc) and we connect to one or another do develop. I'm not in the position to decide whether this decision is good or not, this is a big company and I'm just a developer here. I am just trying to figure out a way to improve things, that's all. I feared that there wouldn't be any clean solution anyway. We'll have to move back to cassini, I fear.